# C# Fill Unused Datagridview Cells

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have to do a datagridview layout to print price labels, but the layout had to be specific to the measure of the paper on the printer, so, my layer has to be something like this

```
X X X X X X X X X
X O O O O O O O O
X O O O O O O O O
X X X X X X X X X
```

Where the crosses need to be empty strings and the circles need to be the info with the pricing. I have all the info of the labels in a listBox1. I created de dgv to 10 columns:

```
dataGridView6.ColumnCount = 10;
```

And I tried to fill the dataGridValue for Row[1], Column[1]

```
string etiq = tokenizer(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), 0) + " " + tokenizer(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), 1);
dataGridView6.Rows[1].Cells[1].Value = etiq;
```

But I get the IndexOutOfRange exception because the previous cells haven't been filled. Is there any way to fill the previous unused cells with empty strings?

Comment: Any chance to provide the full error message?

Comment: ArgumentOutOfTheRangeException
Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. 
Parameter name: index

Comment: did you create any rows for your data grid view?

Comment: No, can I add rows without filling them with the row = {} structure?

Comment: Where is the price data coming from? User input or a database?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had to add the rows with empty values first

```
string[] row = { "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "" };
dataGridView6.Rows.Add(row);
```

Once the row is created I can replace the values with

```
dataGridView6[cols,rows].Value = tokenizer(listBox1.Items[0].ToString(), 0) + " " + tokenizer(listBox1.Items[0].ToString(), 1);
```

This was so basic that I feel ashamed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It would be faster to fill your datasource with empty strings then do it afterwards in the grid.